# How can I load a new view when a user clicks the detail disclosure button on map?

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit

I am making an App that shows annotations on a map using the iOS MapKit.  When a user taps an annotation the callout window pops up and shows the Tile, Subtitle and a Detail Disclosure Button.  I need to have additional information popup when the user taps the Detail Disclosure Button.

This additional information could be a pop-up window or some other view that gets loaded.  I am trying to figure out how best to do this.

Right now I have the Detail Disclosure Button added by using the following code in my annotationView implementation file.  Note the line `self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure]`...and also note that it is being done for THREE annotationTypes:

Here is where it is added:

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{

    iCodeBlogAnnotation *myAnnotation = (iCodeBlogAnnotation*)annotation;

    // setup the if/else statements

    if ([myAnnotation annotationType] == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels)

    {

        self = [super initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth, kHeight);
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];


        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Hotel.png"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(kBorder, kBorder, kWidth - 2 * kBorder, kWidth - 2 * kBorder);
        [self addSubview:imageView];



    }

    else if([myAnnotation annotationType] == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots)

    {

        self = [super initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth, kHeight);
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

         self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];


        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StreetView.jpg"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(kBorder, kBorder, kWidth - 2 * kBorder, kWidth - 2 * kBorder);
        [self addSubview:imageView];



    }

    else if ([myAnnotation annotationType] == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets)

    {
        self = [super initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kWidth, kHeight);
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];


        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Street.png"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(kBorder, kBorder, kWidth - 2 * kBorder, kWidth - 2 * kBorder);
        [self addSubview:imageView];


    }
```

Then, in my viewController implementation file I have the following method to detect when the user has tapped the detail disclosure button:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

{
    // add code here for what you want to do

}
```

What code should I add to the above method in order to load some new pop-up window or new view which would hold the detailed information?

I tried creating a new detailedViewController class and adding the following code to the "add code here" in the above controllTapped method:

```
iCodeBlogMapDetailViewController *dvc = [[iCodeBlogMapDetailViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
```

but nothing happens.

What would be my next step?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Controller implements `MKMapViewDelegate` and set the MKMapView's delegate to the controller.

Comment: Do you mean set this up in the IB? Because I am pretty sure all connections are made

Comment: Yes. If your class implements MKMapViewDelegate and you have set the delegate of your mapview to it, then the code you have above should work. Have you set breakpoints, NSLog etc inside the method to see if control ever reaches there?

Comment: My mapView has a connection between the delegate and file's owner.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code for implementing MKMapViewDelegate for a class, as well as setting the delegate of the mapview?

Comment: My interface of my MapViewController header file is: @interface iCodeBlogMapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
   and in my viewDidLoad method in my implementation file of the same class I have      self.mapView.delegate = self;

Comment: It sounds to me like you have done everything correctly. Are you sure control never makes it inside that method ?

Comment: Control definitely DOES make it inside the method. But nothing happens when I click it

Comment: Hmm .. so the `[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];` does not work?

Comment: It appears that way.  I must be missing the thing that gets pushed or something.  My detailViewController looks like this @implementation iCodeBlogMapDetailViewController




- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
}

Comment: I am not sure. I would suggest adding the DetailViewController as part of a different call and try to figure out why that view does not load. Your problem does not seem to be with the mapview calloutaccessory tapped

Comment: Stupid question...do I need a separate .XIB for the detailViewController?

Comment: Depends .. you can programmatically create a view as well. If you dont have a xib, create a new view controller with a xib just so you can test that this works as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use MKMapView delegate method for this purpose like following, for identifying your `iCodeBlogAnnotation`:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    id <MKAnnotation> annotation = [view annotation];
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[iCodeBlogAnnotation class]])
    {
        iCodeBlogMapDetailViewController *dvc = [[iCodeBlogMapDetailViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];        
    }
}
```

Let me know, If you get it to work

Comment: Nothing happens. I also get the warning "instance method class not found" in my IF statement